# Linked server failed

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, connectivity

I'm trying to set up a linked server, but it still fails and gives an error:

*Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .
Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server is not found or not accessible.*

What could be the problem? I try with powershell from my existing linked server ping with **sqlcmd -S ServerSQL -U User3 -P User3 - OK
but
sqlcmd -S ServerSQL\instance -U User3 -P User3 - failed.**
user3 exists and the password is correct.

I can get to the server but not the instance.
What is the problem? TCP? Firewall?

Comment: You could start with the firewall and go ahead and rule that out.